# Get a reference of an object using class name Java

Tags: java, junit

I'm Running a method annotated with `@Test` and I want get a reference to the object `JunitCore`, this object invokes the method by reflection.

How can I get a reference to the that object, If It's possible?(maybe a security issue)

I tried `reflection` and `classLoader` but I couldn't make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Unless JUnit has a way to inject or give you a reference to the `JunitCore`, you cannot get it, even with reflection.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: What's wrong with `new JunitCore()`?

Comment: @Jon `JunitCore` seems to be the entry point of junit test cases. OP probably wants the instance that gets created in `main`.

Comment: I want to run testCases over ResultAnswer that is in the JunitCore object, to show my dynamic test cases in the eclipse plugin

Comment: Why can't I do this, could you give me an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

The `JUnitCore` is a basic entry point for `Junit` tests. The way it works is it finds a `List` of classes provided as `java` command arguments and uses them to create a `Runner` with which it runs the test cases.

At no point during processing does the `main` method in `JUnitCore` ever pass a reference of the `JUnitCore` instance it creates to any other object. As such, **it is not retrievable either directly or with reflection.**

`JUnitCore` is as follows

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    runMainAndExit(new RealSystem(), args);
}

public static void runMainAndExit(JUnitSystem system, String... args) {
    Result result= new JUnitCore().runMain(system, args);
    system.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
}

public Result runMain(JUnitSystem system, String... args) {
    system.out().println("JUnit version " + Version.id());
    List<Class<?>> classes= new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    List<Failure> missingClasses= new ArrayList<Failure>();
    for (String each : args)
        try {
            classes.add(Class.forName(each));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            system.out().println("Could not find class: " + each);
            Description description= Description.createSuiteDescription(each);
            Failure failure= new Failure(description, e);
            missingClasses.add(failure);
        }
    RunListener listener= new TextListener(system);
    addListener(listener);
    Result result= run(classes.toArray(new Class[0]));
    for (Failure each : missingClasses)
        result.getFailures().add(each);
    return result;
}

... // and more
```

No where in this implementation is a reference to `this` passed as an argument. As such, you cannot get a reference to it.

Comment: I know that I don't have reference, there is no way to get it with code, if there isn't a way, Why?

Comment: @Felquir You'll have to talk to the creators of Junit, that's just how it was designed.

Comment: I'm asking you why I can't get a reference of an object from the jvm in runtime.

Comment: @Felquir For security reasons I guess, but think about it. How would that even work? Which reference? How would you identify it?

Comment: OK I know, there is only one and you don't the answer just guess..., I guess that could be security issues... but guess it isn't an answer. thanks

Comment: @Felquir There happens to be just one in this case. What if there were more?

Comment: Sorry to be repetitive but I want an answer if you tell me you can do this because in the documentation says..., it's fine but if you guess that It isn't an answer

Comment: @Felquir The best documentation is the source code itself. If you follow the execution of `JUnitCore`'s `main` method you'll see that the `JUnitCore` instance is never passed around as an argument to anything. It therefore cannot be accessed. I was guessing about why they did that.

Comment: OK, I think..... let it don't answer again it's useful, I asking one thing and your answer is another.... please

Comment: @Felquir You asked _How can I get a reference to the that object, If It's possible?_ [My answer is _it is not retrievable either directly or with reflection._](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19106216/438154)

Comment: @Felquir Are you serious? You asked _How can I get a reference to the that object_ I'm telling you, **definitely**, you cannot. You asked _If It's possible?_ I'm telling, **definitely**, no, it is not possible. What else do you want?

Comment: @Felquir Why? Because it's not implemented that way. Look at the source code of `JUnitCore`. Also, you cannot use reflection to access a random object in the JVM.

Comment: @Felquir I'm not going to forget it. It's like your blocked somewhere. See the source code in my edit. The `JUnitCore` object is used to setup the tests and call `run()` on a `Runner`. It never passes a `this` reference around so you cannot access it. What more are you looking for?

Comment: looking for a way around, You are telling me something I already know, I investigate this before post.... One answer the object which has all the references to the object is the jvm stack, and you can't access to it because It's a security policy.... do you like my answer?...

Comment: @Felquir There is no way around if you use `JUnitCore` to run your tests. Subclass it or use a completely different class. For example, Eclipse uses `RemoteTestRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a `JunitCore` instance and run the tests yourself:

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
//we can add a listener to listen for events as we run the tests
junit.addListener(new RunListener(){

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("failed " + failure);
    }


});
Result result = junit.run(Class.forName(nameOfTestSuite));
```

Comment: Sorry if I launch another process the result wouldn't show in the plugin. Thanks for your interest